# ASP.NET MVC Newbie: why isn't my model available when creating a strongly-typed view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, strongly-typed-view

I'm starting with ASP.NET MVC, and working with [NerdDinner](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx) as reference. I did the following:

1. Created a new project
2. Added a couple of tables
3. Created LINQ to SQL for them
4. Created a new controller

My Models directory now contains MyModel.dbml, under which I have MyModel.designer.cs, that contains classes for models relating to both of my tables (let's call them Categories and Products).

Now, under my new controller, I would like to create a strongly typed view. So for example I have the following code in my controller (for my application I must work by name, and the "Name" field is unique):

```
    public ActionResult Details(string name)
    {
        MyModelDataContext db = new MyModelDataContext();
        Product user = db.Products.Single(t => t.Name == name);
        return View(user);
    }
```

I would like to create a strongly-typed view. So I right-click the line "`return View(user)`", and choose "Add View...". I click "Create a strongly-typed view". When I click the dropdown of "View data class", I don't see my models, but only:

1. MyProject.Controllers.AccountMembershipService
2. MyProject.Controllers.FormsAuthenticationService

What am I missing?

Comment: Workaround in case you didn't know it - change signature of your view: System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage => System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<YourModel>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recompile your project, the just added model classes do not appear in the list until you've recompiled.

Comment: Sometimes errors on the page will cause your intellisense to bomb out in a view.  Recompile and run (so asp.net compiles your page) sometimes shows where you've screwed up.